# Intuition on the Expected Value and Standard Deviation of a binomial

Tags: probability, statistics, intuition, expected-value, standard-deviation

**Intro:**

Thanks for reading.

I was originally going to ask two separate questions, one on the interpretation of the expected value, and another on the interpretation of the standard deviation, but I feel like they're connected enough to ask them as one.

I'm using the grey lines to separate the first part from the second. Let's begin:

---

**Expected Value:**

Say we have a binomial random variable with $n$ trials and a probability of success of $p$ on each trial.

Its expected value is $np$ - the number of trials multiplied by the probability of success on each trial.

I interpret the expected value in the following way:

If we were to carry out the experiment which this random variable corresponds to $n$ times, we should **expect** the number of successes to be **"around"** $np$.

That's because by the law of large numbers, the **ratio** of the **number of successes** to the **number of trials** should approach the **probability** of success on any **single** trial as the number of trials, $n$, tends towards infinity.

*(I can't really formalize why the law of large numbers works, although it makes intuitive sense...)*

If the total number of successes is around $np$, then...

$$\frac{np}{n} = p$$

...the law of large numbers is satisfied.

Is this interpretation correct?

---

**Standard Deviation:**

The standard deviation of the random variable is $\sqrt{n(p)(1-p)}$.

But...I'm lost on how I should interpret this.

Does it mean that I if I run the experiment $n$ times, I should expect the **actual** number of successes to be...

1. **Less than** $\sqrt{n(p)(1-p)}$ away from the expected value?
2. **Around** $\sqrt{n(p)(1-p)}$ away from the expected value?
3. **In between** $\sqrt{n(p)(1-p)}$ and $2\sqrt{n(p)(1-p)}$ away from the expected value?
4. Does it **depend on the number of trials**?

The first three interpretations all seem to agree with the law of large numbers, as...

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{np \pm k\sqrt{n(p)(1-p)}}{n} = p$$

...regardless of the value of some integer $k$, the ratio of the number of successes to the total number of trials goes to what we defined to be the "probability" of a success on each trial.

I also feel like the number of trials and the probability should matter...but I'm not sure how....

Thanks!

Comment: Consider the experiment of tossing a biased coin $n$ times. The number of successes is $X$. If you repeat this experiment a large number of times, you would predict that the average value of $X$ (over all your repeated experiments) is approximately $np$. You would predict that the average value of $(X - np)^2$ (over all your repeated experiments) is approximately $np(1 - p)$.

Comment: If n is large, the distribution tends to be normal, so 1 happens about 67% of the time.

Answer (score 2):

For one trial where $x=0$ or $x=1$, we get $x^2=x$ so the $$E(x^2)=E(x)=p$$

The variance for one trial is $$ V=E(x^2)-(E(x))^2 = p-p^2= p(1-p)$$

The variance for $n$ trials will be $V=np(1-p)$ therefore, the standard deviation is $\delta =\sqrt {np(1-p)}$